# Azure devops: Branch policies

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have been looking for an elaborated solution to implement below policies in Azure DevOps:

1. Prevent deletion of a branch.
2. Enable a policy which will allow commits into a branch only via PR's and not direct commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Branch policies is the answer. when you enable ANY branch policy this will happen:

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops

Comment: I had already gone through the link. Can you please help me with the navigation where in I can see the information that your image displays?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/_img/branch-policies/save-policy-changes.png?view=azure-devops this image, just before this part of the article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#require-a-minimum-number-of-reviewers